# VSCode extension development - Contribution point for the "Open Editors" section?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm the developer of a VSCode extension that adds items to some context menus. For example, I use the `explorer/context` contribution point to add items to the context menu of the "Explorer" (Folders) section.

I'd like to add similar items to the context menu of the "Open Editors" section... Is there a contribution point I can use in in order to achieve that?

By looking at the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) it doesn't seem to be the case, but I want to make sure. I did try `openEditors/context` without success.

**UPDATE**: [Issue created](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/5184) to improve the documentation about this "Open Editors" view.

Comment: create an doc issue

Comment: @rioV8 Sorry but a "doc issue" would be something wrong with the documentation? Are you saying the contribution point actually exists for that section but should be better documented? If this is the case, I will gladly create the issue.

Comment: that view has a context menu but it is not documented what the name is to use, so it is an issue in the documentation, and if can't be done by extension developers it should be mentioned in the documentation

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is currently not supported, but may be in the future: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/52713